# Replacing values in a column based on a condition in another column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, conditional-statements

I have a data frame where the "Threshold" column is based on the values in the first 4 columns. However, if there is a "Yes" In the Hotspot Column, I want to replace the Threshold value as being "High". So if the dataframe currently looks like this:

| CNV.Gain | Amplification | Homozygous.Deletion.Frequency | Heterozygous.Deletion.Frequency | Hotspot | Threshold |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 5 | 10 | 0 | Yes | Low |
| 0 | 0 | 11 | 8 | No | Medium |
| 7 | 16 | 25 | 0 | No | High |

I would like it to look like this:

| CNV.Gain | Amplification | Homozygous.Deletion.Frequency | Heterozygous.Deletion.Frequency | Hotspot | Threshold |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 5 | 10 | 0 | Yes | High |
| 0 | 0 | 11 | 8 | No | Medium |
| 7 | 16 | 25 | 0 | No | High |

Thank you as always for any help!

Here is the code to replicate the data frame if needed:

#### Data in `dput` format

```
long_fused <-
structure(list(CNV.Gain = c(3L, 0L, 7L), Amplification = c(5L, 
0L, 16L), Homozygous.Deletion.Frequency = c(10L, 11L, 25L), 
Heterozygous.Deletion.Frequency = c(0L, 8L, 0L), Hotspot = c("Yes","No","No",)Threshold = c("Low", "Medium", "High")), class ="data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: The `hotspot`-variable is not present in your `dput`! :-)

Comment: Thanks Serkan, I've just seen and updated that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to make sure that all thresholds are set to "High" when there is a hotspot, try:

```
long_fused <- mutate(long_fused, Threshold = if_else(Hotspot == "Yes", "High", Threshold))
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do a direct replacement -

```
df$Threshold[df$Hotspot == 'Yes'] <- 'High'
df

#  CNV.Gain Amplification Homozygous.Deletion.Frequency
#1        3             5                            10
#2        0             0                            11
#3        7            16                            25

#  Heterozygous.Deletion.Frequency Hotspot Threshold
#1                               0     Yes      High
#2                               8      No    Medium
#3                               0      No      High
```

Comment: This is surely the best answer by far?  Base R, easy conditional replacement based on another column's values with an index call and no looping.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `mutate` and `case_when` to replace the values accordingly.

```
long_fused %>% mutate(
        Threshold = case_when(
                Hotspot == "Yes" ~ "High",
                Hotspot != "Yes" ~ Threshold
        )
)
```

**Edit:** A brief discussion with @Connor about conventions, and general approaches to such questions leads me to this edit and fixing a typo!

```
long_fused %>% mutate(
        Threshold = case_when(
                Hotspot == "Yes" ~ "High",
                TRUE ~ Threshold
        )
)
```

It is convention, and good practise, to use `TRUE ~ Threshold`.

Comment: Wouldn't this set `Threshold` equal to the value in `Hotspot` for all non-yes values?

Comment: Yes - this is correct. OP writes 'However, if there is a "Yes" In the Hotspot Column, I want to replace the Threshold value as being "High"'!

Comment: That much is clear, but your code would overwrite the `Threshold` column with the `Hotspot` column when the second condition evaluates to TRUE. The second condition should read `Hotspot != "Yes" ~ Threshold` or better yet `TRUE ~ Threshold`, not `Hotspot != "Yes" ~ Hotspot`.

Comment: Oh - I see you point! There are two things here though. Firstly, the `Hotspot` colum is, per the post, already defined. Therefore the value is only changed if `Hotspot == "Yes"`. And therefore the answer still works as intended. Secondly, as it is `Yes/No` `TRUE ~ Threshold` is equivalent to `Hotspot != "Yes" ~ Threshold`!

Comment: The `TRUE ~ Threshold` is more convention than anything else--its a good fail safe for input errors! Anyway, my problem with your code is the `~ Hotspot` in the second condition--that needs to be replaced with `~Threshold`. We are updating the `Threshold` column, not the `Hotspot` column.

Comment: I agree! :-) Ill update my answer in your honor!

Comment: @ConnorKrenzer - Ok, now I definetly see your point.... Its late, and I should be doing somehting else it seems. Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235262/discussion-between-serkan-and-connor-krenzer).

Answer (score 2):

We can use replace()

```
long_fused %>% mutate(Threshold = replace(Threshold, Hotspot==“yes”, “High”))
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[Hotspot == 'Yes', Threshold := 'High']
```